# NeverWet: Appropriate for electronics?

Tags: waterproof

The NeverWet superhydrophobic spray is becoming available to consumers.

Are materials like this suitable for protecting circuit boards that may be exposed to water?

http://lancasteronline.com/article/local/861483_Magical-NeverWet-arrives-in-stores.html

Comment: You can protect boards, or yourself, from water by covering the board/yourself with plastic. A raincoat. Silicon coating is used when you don't want to wear a raincoat. Since PCB's aren't made of fabric, this is not an issue. If it was, you probably would not use a spray coating. Spray coating is used when dip or paint is too dificult.

Comment: 5. Does the coating some how trap heat? Kind of like wrapping ones self in plastic and going for a run, could be a bad idea, no?

Answer (score 5):

Without seeing something specific, I would not trust it for electronics.  It might work, but we simply do not know enough about it at this time.  Possible issues:

1. Is the stuff itself conductive or otherwise electro-magneticaly reactive?  It doesn't matter if it keeps the water off, if shorts things out itself.
2. Is the stuff corrosive?
3. Does the water repelling nature break down over time?  I think it does, but don't quote me.
4. Can water still get stuck in cracks and crevices?  I guess that it can, since you can't spray it everywhere.

It is hard to beat a water barrier, which this stuff is not.  It would be cool if I'm wrong, but I'm not going to bet on it.